# Euler's identity to simplfy fraction

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I simplify a fraction that has a complex number in the numerator, and an exponential function in the denominator where the exponents are of the form $(a+bi)t$? Example:

$$\dfrac{1.5 + 0.75i}{e^{(1 + 2i)t}}$$

Answer (score 0):

we can simplify $$\begin{align}\dfrac{1.5 + 0.75i}{e^{(1 + 2i)t}} &= 0.75e^{-t}(\cos 2t - i \sin 2t)(2+ i)\\
& =  0.75e^{-t}\left((2\cos 2t +\sin 2t) + i(\cos 2t - 2 \cos 2t) \right)
\end{align}$$